# cordova build android not runing on device

Tags: phonegap, cordova, framework7

Добрый день. 
Компилирую приложение в дебага, устанавливаю его на телефон и все нормально работает.

После того как я скомпилировал приложение в режиме релиза,

```
cordova build android --release
```

CLI ошибок не выдал вообще! 
Но установить приложение на телефон не получилось. Просто пишет что не удалось установить.

Подскажите в чем проблема. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Перед установкой релиза на устройство, удалите с телефона предыдущие версии этого приложения (те что были собраны без --release)